# Filter Using Select Dropdown in laravel livewire

Tags: php, laravel, filter, dropdown

I have a select dropdown in view page, and I made function in the livewire components. The filter works fine but the problem is when I filter jobs using dropdown, it filters the data but not showing the other inputs inside the dropdown. I have to go back to select another input to filter. Kindly someone help me with this.

Here is my function in livewire component

```
class Index extends Component
{
    public $jobs, $jobInput = [];

    protected $queryString = ['jobInput'];

    public function render()
    {
        $this->jobs = CreateJob::where('status', '1')->when($this->jobInput, function ($query) {
            $query->where('job_title', $this->jobInput);
        })->get();
        return view('livewire.frontend.job.index', ['jobs' => $this->jobs]);
    }
}
```

Here is my view page

```
<div class="card-body">
    @if ($jobs)
        <label class="d-block">
            <select class="form-control" name="jobInput" wire:model="jobInput"    id="jobInput">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                @foreach ($jobs as $job)
                    <<option value="{{ $job->job_title }}">{{ $job->job_title }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </label>   
    @endif
</div>
```

Here is my output

[image]
[image]

See the dropdown shows only the selected results. I want to show like in the first image even after filtering.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this block:

```
->when($this->jobInput, function ($query) {
        $query->where('job_title', $this->jobInput);
})
```

Because whenever `$this->jobInput` exists the `where` query in `when` will work.

If you want to make it selected in dropdown you have to do it in the `@foreach` loop inside the view.